# How to remove any words containing two adjacent characters with different in both cases and letters?

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, combinatorics

I have a list of permutations of `ABCabc` and I want to remove any permutations with two adjacent characters with different in both cases (uppercase and lowercase) and letters.

For example,

- `ABCcab` is kept.
- `ABCacb` must be removed because `Ca` contains two adjacent characters with different cases.
- `AbBcaC` must be removed as well.

## Attempt

Here is my attempt but without filtering.

```
Select[StringJoin /@ Permutations[Characters@"ABCabc"],....]
```

Comment: To be fair, I choose the faster. Thank  you!

Comment: You first example also has 2 adjacent characters of different cases = Cc

Comment: @TonyEnnis: Fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
slist = StringJoin /@ Permutations[Characters@"ABCabc"]; 

pat =  a_ ~~ b_ /; ToUpperCase[a] != ToUpperCase[b] && UpperCaseQ[a] != UpperCaseQ[b];

Select[StringFreeQ[pat]]@slist
```

> ```
> {"ABCcab", "ABCcba", "ABbacC", "ACBbac", "ACBbca", "ACcabB", 
> "AabBCc", "AabcCB", "AacCBb", "AacbBC", "BACcab", "BACcba", "BAabcC", 
> "BCAabc", "BCAacb", "BCcbaA", "BbaACc", "BbacCA", "BbcCAa", "BbcaAC", 
> "CABbac", "CABbca", "CAacbB", "CBAabc", "CBAacb", "CBbcaA", "CcaABb", 
> "CcabBA", "CcbBAa", "CcbaAB", "aABCcb", "aABbcC", "aACBbc", "aACcbB", 
> "abBACc", "abcCAB", "abcCBA", "acCABb", "acbBAC", "acbBCA", "bBACca", 
> "bBAacC", "bBCAac", "bBCcaA", "baABCc", "bacCAB", "bacCBA", "bcCBAa", 
> "bcaABC", "bcaACB", "cCABba", "cCAabB", "cCBAab", "cCBbaA", "caACBb", 
> "cabBAC", "cabBCA", "cbBCAa", "cbaABC", "cbaACB"}
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this?:

```
DeleteCases[StringJoin /@ Permutations[Characters@"ABCabc"], 
 s_String /; 
  StringMatchQ[s,
    ___ ~~ a_ ~~ b_ ~~ ___ /;
     ! LowerCaseQ[a <> b] &&
     ! UpperCaseQ[a <> b] && 
     ToLowerCase[a] =!= ToLowerCase[b]]]
```

Comment: Thank  you very much.